# Two AJAX functions inside, it works one or the other but mutually exclusive

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the piece of code which I refer to:
The first ajax call is: `$.ajax(urlHoveringBtn)`, the second is `$.ajax(url)`
Just one or the other element. What's wrong?

```
$(document).on("click", "a.selection", function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var isLive = $this.data("live");
    var url = "/" + _language + "/BetSlip/Add/" + $this.data("selection") + "?odds=" + $this.data("odds") + "&live=" + isLive;
    var urlHoveringBtn = "/" + _language + '/BetSlip/AddHoveringButton/' + $this.data("selection") + "?odds=" + $this.data("odds") + "&live=" + isLive;

    $.ajax(urlHoveringBtn).done(function (dataBtn) {
        if ($(".betslip-access-button").length == 0 && dataBtn.length > 0) {
            $("body").append(dataBtn);
        }
    });

    $.ajax(url).done(function (data) {
        if ($(".betslip-access").length == 0 && data.length > 0) {
            $(".navbar").append(data);
        }
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $this.addClass("in-betslip");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?  What happens here?  Where are `$(".betslip-access-button")` and `$(".betslip-access")` coming from?  You are aware that there is no guarantee as to which AJAX call will finish first, yes?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... What are you expecting to happen? What actually happens? What debugging have you attempted?

Comment: As you can see there are two modifiyng to the document: $("body").append(dataBtn) and $(".navbar").append(data) wich should happen. But either one or the other are visible. Not them both together..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).on("click", "a.selection", function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var isLive = $this.data("live");
        var url = "/" + _language + "/BetSlip/Add/" + $this.data("selection") + "?odds=" + $this.data("odds") + "&live=" + isLive;
        var urlHoveringBtn = "/" + _language + '/BetSlip/AddHoveringButton/' + $this.data("selection") + "?odds=" + $this.data("odds") + "&live=" + isLive;

    var ajax1 = $.ajax(urlHoveringBtn);

    var ajax2 = $.ajax(url);

    $.when( ajax1, ajax2 ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
        if ($(".betslip-access-button").length == 0 && a1.length > 0) {
                $("body").append(a1);
        }

      if ($(".betslip-access").length == 0 && a2.length > 0) {
            $(".navbar").append(a2);
        }
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $this.addClass("in-betslip");
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

`$.when` will make sure both the ajax calls were resolved and then executes the call back.

`a1` and `a2` are the response of the ajax calls `ajax1` and `ajax2`

for more info check the `$.when` docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score -1):

`urlHoveringBtn` and `url` should be object here, not string. like:

```
var urlHoveringBtn = {
    url: "/" + _language + '/BetSlip/AddHoveringButton/' + $this.data("selection"),
    data : {
       odds : $this.data("odds"),
       live : isLive
    }
}
```

Do same for `url`, this should work. Good luck!

Comment: This is not correct http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. The string argument is valid.

Comment: Wrong:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  the `jQuery.ajax` method accepts just URL as the parameter.